# Comparing Character, Integer and similar types in Java: Use equals or ==?

Tags: java, equals, primitive

I wanted to make sure about something in Java:
If I have a Character or an Integer or a Long and those sort of things, should I use equals or is == sufficient?

I know that with strings there are no guarantees that there is only one instance of each unique string, but I'm not sure about other boxed types.

My intuition is to use equals, but I want to make sure I'm not wasting performance.

Comment: never assume anything about performance - test it.  perhaps == and .equals will have about the same performance, in which case the question is moot.

Comment: The only thing to assume about performance: it doesn't matter if incorrect code is faster.  :-)

Comment: That's what I wanted to make sure.

Comment: As for *"I know that with strings there are no guarantees that there is only one instance of each unique string"*: if for some reason you'd ever need that, see [String#intern()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

EDIT: The spec makes *some* guarantees for boxing conversions. From [section 5.1.7](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.1.7):

> If the value p being boxed is true,
>   false, a byte, a char in the range
>   \u0000 to \u007f, or an int or short
>   number between -128 and 127, then let
>   r1 and r2 be the results of any two
>   boxing conversions of p. It is always
>   the case that r1 == r2.

The implementation *can* use a larger pool, mind you.

I would *really* avoid writing code which relies on that though. Not because it might fail, but because it's not obvious - few people will know the spec that well. (I previously thought it was implementation-dependent.)

You should use `equals` or compare the underlying values, i.e.

```
if (foo.equals(bar))
```

or

```
if (foo.intValue() == bar.intValue())
```

Note that even if the autoboxing were guaranteed to use fixed values, other callers can always create separate instances anyway.

Comment: IIRC, the JLS says at least -128 to 127 for byte, short and int, wither equivalent for char but not for long, float or short. IIRC, 6u14 and previous performance releases allow pool size to be configured through a system property.

Comment: Wow, you're right. I could have sworn it gave leeway to pool or not pool. Will edit.

Comment: @Tom you mentioned short twice. In reality, there is a pool of the same size for short and long. You could say that Boolean was always pooled.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to compare any two objects for equality use `.equals()`.

Even (and especially) if those objects are the primitive wrapper types `Byte`, `Character`, `Short`, `Integer`, `Long`, `Float`, `Double` and `Boolean`.

For objects "`==`" only ever compares the object identity and that's very, very rarely what you want. And you de-facto never what you want with the primitive wrappers.

Only use `==` in one of those two scenarios:

1. all values involved in the comparison are primitive types (and preferably not floating point numbers)
2. you really want to know if two references refer to the same object (this includes comparison of `enum`s, because there the value is bound to the object identity)

Comment: scenario 3: You are comparing enum instances or some other immutable type that manages its instances in a way that allows == to be safe.

Comment: your scenario 3 is the same as scenario 2

Comment: @TofuBeer: technically, yes, but many people won't think of it that way.

Answer (score 5):

[Java Language Spec 5.1.7](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.1.7):

> If the value p being boxed is true,
>   false, a byte, a char in the range
>   \u0000 to \u007f, or an int or short
>   number between -128 and 127, then let
>   r1 and r2 be the results of any two
>   boxing conversions of p. It is always
>   the case that r1 == r2.

and:

> Discussion
>
> Ideally, boxing a given primitive
>   value p, would always yield an
>   identical reference. In practice, this
>   may not be feasible using existing
>   implementation techniques. The rules
>   above are a pragmatic compromise. The
>   final clause above requires that
>   certain common values always be boxed
>   into indistinguishable objects. The
>   implementation may cache these, lazily
>   or eagerly.
>
> For other values, this formulation
>   disallows any assumptions about the
>   identity of the boxed values on the
>   programmer's part. This would allow
>   (but not require) sharing of some or
>   all of these references.
>
> This ensures that in most common
>   cases, the behavior will be the
>   desired one, without imposing an undue
>   performance penalty, especially on
>   small devices. Less memory-limited
>   implementations might, for example,
>   cache all characters and shorts, as
>   well as integers and longs in the
>   range of -32K - +32K.

So, in some cases == will work, in many others it will not.  Always use .equals to be safe since you cannot grantee (generally) how the instances were obtained.

If speed is a factor (most .equals start with an == comparison, or at least they should) AND you can gurantee how they were allocated AND they fit in the above ranges then == is safe.

Some VMs may increase that size, but it is safer to assume the smallest size as specified by the langauge spec than to rely on a particular VM behaviour, unless you really really really need to.

Answer (score 4):

```
//Quick test
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Are they equal? "+ (new Long(5) == new Long(5)));
  }
}
```

Output:

"Are they equal? 0"

Answer:

No, they're not equal.  You must use .equals or compare their primitive values.

Comment: How about Long.valueOf(5) == Long.valueOf(5) ?

Comment: new Long(...) is definitely going to give you a *different* reference each time. No surprise there. Long.valueOf(...) however is going to pool references. Like Maurice said, your test is not the right one in that instance.

Comment: since you may not know how the Long was obtained, using == would almost never be safe.

Comment: Indeed, TofuBeer is correct.  There are certainly ways to get two actually-identical Longs, especially as he noted in his answer.  It's still a terrible idea to rely on those ways, since if you changed those Longs later, you wouldn't think about how the way you compare them for equality changed too.

Comment: CaptainAwesomePants needs only show one instance in which == fails in order to prove that you cannot universally rely on ==, even if there are some cases where it happens to work.

Answer (score 2):

Implementations of the equals(Object o) method almost always start with

```
if(this == o) return true;
```

so using `equals` even if `==` is true is really not much of a performance hit.

I recommend always* using the `equals` method on objects.

** of course there are a very few times when you should not take this advice.*

Answer (score 1):

The general answer is **no**, you are not guaranteed that for the same numeric value, the Long objects you get are the same (even if you restrict yourself to using Long.valueOf()).

However, it is possible that you would get a performance improvement by first trying to test the equality of references (using ==) and then, if failed, trying equals(). It all hinges on the comparative costs of the additional == test and the method call... Your mileage may vary, but it is worth trying a simple loop test to see which is better.

Answer (score 1):

It is worth noting that auto-boxed values will uses pooled object if they are available. This is why (Integer) 0 == (Integer) 0 but (Integer) 128 != (Integer) 128 for Java 6u13

Answer (score 1):

I like to see the result visually:

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
        Integer a = 126; //no boxed up conversion, new object ref
        Integer b = 126; //no boxed up conversion, re-use memory address
        System.out.println("Are they equal? " + (a == b)); // true
        Integer a1 = 140; //boxed up conversion, new object
        Integer b1 = 140; //boxed up conversion, new object
        System.out.println("Are they equal? " + (a1 == b1)); // false
        System.out.println("Are they equal? " + (new Long(5) == new Long(5))); // false
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`==` compares the object reference while `equals(Object obj)` compares for object equality. *If there can ever be more than one instance of an equals object in existence* then you **must** use `equals` for equality comparison.

Examples:

```
Integer i1 = new Integer(12345);
Integer i2 = new Integer(12345);
```

these are different object instances but are equal according to Integer's equality, so you must use `equals(Object obj)`

```
public enum Gender {
    MALE, FEMALE;
}
```

in this case there will only be one instance of `FEMALE` in existence so `==` is safe to use.